# Why was my duplicate question flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

I was wondering if someone could shed some light on the use of the duplicate question flag. It's not normally a flag I use, but in the case of [how to preload sounds in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516652/how-to-preload-sounds-in-javascript) it seemed like the correct flag. This is a question that there are few hundred results for specifically for javascript. I found [How to preload a sound in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313646/how-to-preload-a-sound-in-javascript), which appeared to be the perfect answer. I flagged duplicated, entered [How to preload a sound in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313646/how-to-preload-a-sound-in-javascript) as the duplicate, and... it was disputed. I just cannot fathom a good reason to dispute my flag with how little info was provided in the original question. Any ideas?

Comment: It was disputed as a result of a triage review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/10719077 . The way triage handles close votes changed recently, but it's easy to see why something could simultaneously "Look OK" to reviewers and yet be a duplicate of something else.

Comment: @BradLarson Is there a review in the close vote review queue, or are reviews not created there from flags if there's an uncompleted triage review?

Comment: @BradLarson thank you! I now understand why it happened, but it does not seem to be a great way to handle close tags to me...

Comment: @Servy - The triage review took 15 minutes, and the duplicate flag came five minutes before the completion of that. I think the timing on this was such that the triage review ended up disputing the flag before a close review could even be started. Had the flag come just a little bit later, this probably would have been reviewed as normal.

Comment: @BradLarson So close vote reviews *aren't* opened as a result of close flags on questions with an open triage review?  Or was a close review created and the triage just completed before the close vote queue could accept/reject the flag?

Comment: @Servy - I think the triage review completed so quickly (five minutes after the flag was cast) that it never made it to the close review queue before the flag was invalidated. Not sure if the close vote review would have continued had it been initiated in that period.

Comment: @BradLarson Are votes to close (not flags to close) prevented from creating a review in close vote review if there's an active triage review, as flags are?

Comment: Close review won't start while a question is still in triage, regardless of timing. Also, **votes** are never disputed (or declined), @Servy.

Comment: @Shog9 True, but keeping the question out of the VTC queue makes it quite a lot harder for it to actually get closed, even if the initial vote still counts.

Comment: It enters close review after it exits triage, @Servy. IF it has any votes or active flags. Not much point to Triage if you send everything to close review anyway. You can't say it makes it harder to close things; close votes are a limited resource, and shoving EVERYTHING into close review was actually counter-productive.

Comment: @Shog9 That's fine then.  I didn't realize it'd end up in the VTC queue if there's an active close flag on it, even if triage marks it as okay.

Comment: Well, it won't - because Triage will dispute such flags. Votes are sacrosanct though; Triage won't touch 'em, regardless of the outcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with all disputed flags, it just means that others disagreed with you. Doesn't mean you were wrong, just that a few other people didn't see it that way.

You did manage to convince someone though, and it just so happens that this someone had the power to close the post. So it ended well.

Generally you can ignore disputed flags; they are the signal that you are part of a large and diverse group of people.