# Is it okay for a single user to edit all the posts (A question and all its answers)?

Tags: discussion, edits

A few times, I come across a question that needs editing, and a number of answers of that question, also need editing. Like [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915443/dependent-destroy-how-does-this-work), where I edited the question and all the answers. So does it seem superfluous or 'exaggerating yourself'?

Comment: You should edit every post that you can improve by doing so, it's as simple as that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think like you; you think like I do, but not everyone thinks like everyone esle does. Therefore, I asked this question.

Comment: ...who doesn't? Has somebody commented on your edits or something? The three edits you link to all seem legit.

Comment: What is the question here? If people will agree with your actions? Yes they will. Or that people will disagree with your actions? Yes they will.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, nobody has told me so. I was just my own thinking.

Comment: @Gimby The question here is: How does it sound to the community? Does it sound good, and now I think it sounds good.

Comment: I did this quite many times, and there were no complaints. One thing that I always tried when doing this is to edit all the posts quickly to prevent intermittent bumps due to edit.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks; that's good to know.

Comment: `...that is as fellows` is it a typo?

Comment: @ArslanAli I would read this somewhat related question and particularly [shog9's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314660/424903), and stop worrying about the community. Worrying about staying with the site rules is already effort enough.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> So does it seem superfluous or 'exaggerating yourself'?

Nope. Edit any posts that you figure need improving, regardless of the vicinity to other posts you've edited. If anyone disagrees with your edits, they can suggest an edit, or apply their own if they have that privilege.

An editor can be pinged in the comments below a post, so if anyone sees any egregious edits, they can ping the editor. I suggest that you continue improving the quality of the content on the site as you are now. If anyone has a problem with an edit, deal with that at that point.