# Why is this question not a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49973443/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level-request-m) as duplicate of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level) and it was disputed. After reading [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314637/why-was-my-duplicate-question-flag-disputed) I see that a disputed flag means others disagreed.

In the interest of my future dupe flagging, what about this question makes others feel it is not a duplicate?

I flagged because

- It has essentially the same title as the previous question
- The top answers on both questions are giving the same advice
- The previous question has many relevant and useful answers

I am missing something and don't want to wrongly flag questions as duplicates.

What makes this new question unique from the previous?

Comment: You should read the answer to [the linked post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314637/why-was-my-duplicate-question-flag-disputed) again - "[A disputed flag] doesn't mean you were wrong ... Generally you can ignore disputed flags". Don't spend too much time worrying about others occasionally disagreeing with you - if it never happens, you're probably not doing any moderation tasks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Triage is what you're missing.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19517557) Duplicate flags really don't survive Triage well.

To me, it looks like your flag was correct.

Unfortunately, Triage is largely considered a broken queue. On top of this, from what I remember, reviewers aren't shown that a post was flagged as duplicate in the queue. Honestly, that *does* make sense. Triage is *supposed* to be a "look it over, toss it in a bucket, move on to the next one" style queue, and the reviews there aren't supposed to take long, so duplicates don't really fit that model.

Keep doing what you're doing, hopefully someone else sees these posts and handles the closure.

Comment: In theory the triage reviewers could have read the possible duplicate comment to know that there was a duplicate flag, but there's good odds many/all of the reviewers didn't see it.

Comment: That, and by the time they did check and compare, even as quickly as this one could've been done, someone else would've just ignored the comments and clicked "Looks OK" on the review.

Comment: The post spend almost an entire hour in Triage.  The final vote is 55 minutes after the first.

Comment: `Triage is largely considered a broken queue` Source? I see Triage as a very successful queue that processes tons of posts every day, with some occasional mistakes due to human error. Sure, we hear about some of the flags that go awry in Triage, but for the most part I see Triage as working rather well. If you have any statistics or data though that suggest otherwise, I'd be happy to learn from them though.

Comment: @DavyM Go through feature requests here for Triage queue- I might admittedly be biased, but from what I've seen? Correct flags get declined, junk gets sent to H&I (admittedly might be fixed if they would finally fix the guidance wording), and bad posts fly right on under the radar. I'm not privy to data, unfortunately. (And I've never played much with SEDE so it'd take a while to write a query.)

Comment: @DavyM The [main problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292316/) is that Triage has the poorly named **Requires Editing** button. So people (incorrectly) assume that means that *it kicks it back to the OP to edit*, when, in reality, it kicks it to H&I for *other people to edit*. Since it's rare you can fix someone else's question, it tends to make H&I is cesspool of bad Triage reviews. SO has made it clear they won't fix it either

Comment: If Triage's design is contrary to evaluating possible duplicates, then a duplicate flag should exclude it from Triage.

Comment: @jpmc26 I think there's been a feature request to that effect, but I could be wrong. I might see if I can find it... Edit: [Pretty sure this is what I was thinking of.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332703/duplicate-flags-shouldnt-be-disputed-on-a-question-that-looks-ok)

Answer (score 8):

The post [went through triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19517557) a minute after you cast your flag, where three users said "it looks okay", thus disputing all close flags on the post.

Comment: Except that none of the three users even saw the close flags. How is that considered a dispute? Something is broken here.

Comment: Why would 'It looks okay' dispute flags? There are a lot of close reasons, 'Looks okay' can't possibly cover all of them.